# Apt return type for this function

Tags: c#

Here is a small snippet from a C# program to generate dictionary from file.

```
var _mappings = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var splitt = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return new fooclass
        {
            foo = abc[0],
            foo1 = abc[1],
            foo2 = abc[2],
        };
    })
    .ToDictionary<fooclass, string>(mkey => mkey.abc[0]);
```

I am in a dilemma that on how to return this dictionary from the function. Returning weak types is not considered good in function, and var itself cannot be a return type.

So, what would be ideal in such a case?

Comment: `Dictionary<fooclass, string>`?

Comment: It is already strongly typed as you specified `ToDictionary<fooclass, string>`. What is the problem, actually?

Comment: I take it _mappings is of type Dictionary<fooclass, string> ? what's wrong with returning that type?

Comment: [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) simply instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the value on the right side.

Comment: I did try that and got this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,fooclass>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<foolcass,string>'. Looks like there has to be some way of explicity specificying the key for the retunred dictionary format.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your logic here. What you want to have as a key and what as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's any helpful, the following compiles.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Dictionary<char, ScoresandPercentiles> function()
    {
        var _mappings = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(line =>
            {
                var splitt = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                return new ScoresandPercentiles
                {
                    foo = splitt[0],
                    foo1 = splitt[1],
                    foo2 = splitt[2],
                };
            }).ToDictionary(mkey => mkey.foo[0]);
        return _mappings;
    }
}

internal class ScoresandPercentiles
{
    public string foo;
    public string foo1;
    public string foo2;
}
```

Comment: If you do not really need dictionary, you can also do `.ToList();` and have a return type of `List<ScoresandPercentiles>`

Answer (score 1):

`var` is not a type, and it's not weak or dynamic. It's mereley telling the compiler to figure out what type it is. In this case it will be the type returned by the `ToDictionary` method, which would be a `Dictionary<fooclass, string>`.

Comment: I did try that and got this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,fooclass>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<foolcass,string>'. Looks like there has to be some way of explicity specificying the key for the retunred dictionary format. –

Comment: You will need to make sure that the order of the type arguments match: a `Dictionary<string,fooclass>` is obviously not the same as a `Dictionary<fooclass,string>`. The first type argument is the type for the keys, the second is for the values.

Comment: The order specified in method is correct and matching to `_mappings` and that's what the problem is. It's prompting with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your code so that the key is `char`:

```
ToDictionary<char, fooclass>(mkey => mkey.abc[0]);
```

And you can return it from your function as that.

Comment: How to tell the `key` for the Dictionary, with simple declaration?

Comment: I think you should post such questions as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,fooclass>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<foolcass,string>'`. Looks like there has to be some way of explicity specificying the key for the retunred dictionary format.